# Access Azure storage from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-storage

I am new to azure storage and I have a python files that needs some csv files stored in azure storage , I want to use them in the python script , how i do that exactly

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=environment-variable-windows.